# submitting the form without waiting for AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$('#form1').submit(function () {
    var filal = $('input#l_email').val().length && $('input#l_pswd').val().length;
    if (!(filal)) {
        $("div#login_feed").fadeIn(400);
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('hello')
        $.post('create_login.php', {
            lemail: $('input#email').val(),
            lpswd: $('input#pswd').val()
        }, function (result) {
            if (result == 'sucess') return true;
            else return false;
        });
    }
});
```

I am unable to find where the bug is. If it enters into `if` block, it won't submit the form but I do not know what's going wrong. When it enters `else` block, it alerts hello and automatically submits the form without waiting for the completion of AJAX request. I know the code is creepy with too may return statements but I am new to jQuery style so kindly let me know the way to do it.

Comment: The return true and false inside the ajax happens LONG after the submit handler has returned undefined, thus causing the form to submit normally.

Comment: You have a typo in your code - your var is `filall`, with three `l`s, but your condition tests `filal`.

Comment: so how do i stop the form submitting and submit it only after AJAX request ?  @KevinB

Comment: you stop it immediately then trigger the submit when you want it to submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return out of an asynchronous callback:

```
var x = setTimeout(function(){
    return "foobar";
},1000)
console.log(x); // the id of the settimeout instead of "foobar"
```

The same thing happens with your ajax request.

```
var foo = (function(){
    $.post("foo.php",function(){
        return "foobar";
    })
})();
console.log(foo); // undefined because your function didn't return anything!!
```

In your case, you need to stop the default action completely then submit the form after the ajax request.

```
$('#form1').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // stop default action
    const theform = this;
    const bothFilled = $('#l_email').val().length && $('#l_pswd').val().length;
    if (bothFilled) {
        $.post('create_login.php', {
            lemail: $('#email').val(),
            lpswd: $('#pswd').val()
        }, function (result) {
            if (result === 'success') theform.submit(); // submit form, bypassing jQuery bound submit handler to prevent infinite loop
        });
    } else {    
        $("#login_feed").fadeIn(400);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks and using this  $('#form').trigger('submit') instead of $('#form').submit() makes any difference? Just want to know

Comment: no, it does not, but this is not you want. The gem in the code here is the difference between `theform` and `$("#form1")` - the former being DOM element and the latter - jquery wrapper. `theform.submit()` will not trigger jquery event again recursively.

Comment: Yes, it makes a HUGE difference. using `$("#form").trigger("submit")` will trigger the jQuery-bound event, causing an infinite loop. `$("#form")[0].submit()` on the other hand **does not** trigger the jQuery-bound event, thus avoiding the infinite loop. `$("#form")[0]` gives you a Form Element rather than a jQuery object containing a form element, thus you are using the form element's submit method rather than the jQuery object's submit method.

Comment: its not submitting it enters the if block result=="sucess" but theform.submit does not seem to work .

Comment: rename your submit button from "submit" to something else.

Comment: I have did but still its not submitting

Answer (score 1):

The submit action send the form by default, you need to stop that with preventDefault();

```
$('#form1').submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#form1').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var filal = $('#l_email').val().length && $('#l_pswd').val().length;
    if (!(filal)) {
        $("div#login_feed").fadeIn(400);
    } else {
        $.post('create_login.php', {
            lemail: $('#email').val(),
            lpswd: $('#pswd').val()
        }, function (result) {
            if (result == 'sucess')
                $('#form1').get().submit();

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I left it as is, but you misspelled success.

Comment: this will recursively trigger the jquery bound submit event, you need to instead trigger it on the formNode, see my answer.

Comment: Not sure if you really wanted to do another submit.  You've already created the login, why not just window.location to somewhere afterwards?